# t.time saving field as a string in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table with a field called `time_start`. Example:

```
t.time :time_start
```

When I try to save the attribute, it saves it as a Hash-String. Example:

```
params{
       "time_start(1i)"=>"2016",
       "time_start(2i)"=>"10",
       "time_start(3i)"=>"12",
       "time_start(4i)"=>"23",
       "time_start(5i)"=>"59",
}

=> "{1=>2016, 2=>10, 3=>12, 4=>23, 5=>59}"
```

I cannot figure out why the attribute is saving a string instead of parsing into a Time obj. I have even tried a `rake db:rollback VERSION=123456546` to the migration just before it, but it still saves the value as a string after the `rake db:migrate`. I am not allowed to drop the table.

Comment: Which Rails version and database do you use?

Comment: `Rails 4.2.1` and `postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.9`

Comment: Nothing special. Can you post your model and asignment too?

Answer (score 0):

Looking back through the commits, a Junior dev originally assigned the `time_start` field as a `string` data-type in table `B`. The solution was to grab the version number of the previous migration (table `A`), and run `rake db:migrate VERSION=213412341234`, then `rake db:migrate`. It is now saving correctly.